# Zookeeper - monitoring leader when leaderServes=no

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I recently scaled out a zookeeper cluster, and as part of the configuration change, we set

```
leaderServes=no
```

in order to increase throughput. This has worked out great, except for one problem: the leader no longer responds to (most) four letter words, replying to any inquiries with the message

```
This ZooKeeper instance is not currently serving requests
```

I get it dear leader, you're not doing the menial work anymore, but ... could the monitoring software still get your status and metrics?

I really hope there's a work around that isn't "use JMX". Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Did you check something like Exhibitor? I never used it, but I heard that somebody use it for management. http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/04/introducing-exhibitor-supervisor-system.html

Comment: There is a bug open on this issue, but it has received little attention over the years [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1281).  You could signup and vote for the issue to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

No , it cann't . This is what `leaderServes=no` functions , the leader refuses all the client commands .

```
//org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Leader#lead
if (!System.getProperty("zookeeper.leaderServes", "yes").equals("no")) {
   self.cnxnFactory.setZooKeeperServer(zk);
 }
```